# Tratar fecha en php "2017-09-02T00:00:00.000Z",

Tags: date

Muy buenas, recibo este forma de fecha  en un Json: `2017-09-02T00:00:00.000Z` y me gustaría poder tratartala para convertirla en `dd/MM/YYYY`. Existe la funcíon en php? Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP tiene la función [`date_format`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-format.php) para ello, que es un alias de [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php)

En cuanto al [formato](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) `dd/MM/YYYY`, en PHP se expresaría así: `"d/m/Y"`, donde:

- `d`: Día del mes, 2 dígitos con ceros iniciales
- `m`: Representación numérica de un mes, con ceros iniciales
- `Y`: Una representación numérica completa de un año, 4 dígitos

Ejemplo de código:

```
$str='2017-09-02T00:00:00.000Z';
$formato = 'd/m/Y'; 
$fecha=date_format(date_create($str), $formato);
echo $fecha;
```

O... si lo quieres en una sola línea:

```
echo date_format(date_create('2017-09-02T00:00:00.000Z'), 'd/m/Y');
```

Resultado:

```
02/09/2017
```

---

O... si te gusta la Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO),  creas un objeto fecha a partir de tu cadena usando la clase [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php):

```
$str='2017-09-02T00:00:00.000Z';
$formato = 'd/m/Y'; 
$oFecha = new DateTime($str); //Aquí se crea un objeto fecha a partir de la cadena
$fecha= $oFecha->format($formato); //Aquí extraes la fecha según el formato y puedes seguir usando $oFecha para otras cosas si lo necesitas
echo $fecha;
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `strtotime` y `date` para lo que deseas.

`strtotime` convierte a fecha unix

`date` le proporciona el formato que deseas.

```
echo date('d/m/y',strtotime('2017-09-02T00:00:00.000Z'));
```